# count of multiple partially matching DNA sequences

Tags: r, dna-sequence

I have a dataset of partially matching DNA sequences and want to assign different numerical indexes to the partially matching sequences.

i.e.:

```
sequences <- c("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
               "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
               "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCC",
               "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACC",
               "CATTTTCAG", 
               "CATTTTCAGTCAAAATTT", 
               "CATG", 
               "CATGG", 
               "CATGGGTT", 
               "GATC")
```

The first one recurs in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th and they should all get a value 1, the 5th recurs in the 6th and they should all get a 2, the 7th  recurs in the 8th and 9th and should all get a 3, the 10th does not recur and should get 4 as index. This is just an example of course, sometimes the dataset could contain >3000 rows.

I tried several solutions including grepl and str_count. The latest one of the attempts was to create a dictionary first to store all the sequences and the indices, create a list of prefixes and then iterate the prefixes to assign the indices. However the result is not what I expect as all the sequences get a index of 1.

```
# Create a dictionary to store the sequences and their indices
indices <- as.list(1:length(sequences))
names(indices) <- sequences

# Create a function that returns the first 7 characters of a sequence
get_prefix <- function(seq) {
  return(substring(seq, 1, 7))
}

# Create a list of unique prefixes
prefixes <- unique(sapply(sequences, get_prefix))

# Iterate over the prefixes and assign the same index to all sequences that start with the same prefix
for (i in 1:length(prefixes)) {
  prefix <- prefixes[i]
  seqs <- sequences[sapply(sequences, get_prefix) == prefix]
  indices[seqs] <- which.min(indices[seqs])
}

# Print the final indices
print(indices)
```

Any help is welcome! thanks!

Comment: What if a sequence contains more than two matches? e.g. CATGGGATC, it will match your 7th, 8th and 10th sequences.

Answer (score 0):

This problem relates to grouping using relational data. You can use `grep` + `igraph` to do so:

```r
library(igraph)
sapply(sequences, grep, sequences, value = TRUE) |>
  stack() |>
  graph.data.frame() |>
  clusters() |>
  getElement("membership") |>
  stack()

   values                                ind
1       1                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2       1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
3       1    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCC
4       1        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACC
5       2                          CATTTTCAG
6       2                 CATTTTCAGTCAAAATTT
7       3                               CATG
8       3                              CATGG
9       3                           CATGGGTT
10      4                               GATC
```